# Getting value from checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of different checkbox and equate them to a price and calculate the price. Below is my code, when I submit my form, it does not append the price.

I've tried equating the price to each value using switch case.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var checked = [];
        $(".sizes[value='items[]']:checked").each(function () {
            checked.push($(this).val());
            var price = 0;
            switch (checked) {
                case "small":
                    price:450;

                    break;
                case "medium":
                    price:750

                    break;
                case "large":
                    price:1500

                    break;
                default:
                    checked;

            }

            $(".add").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(".sprice").append(pname);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I want to find the total of all checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

The checkboxes should have the value, don't set the prices in the jQuery. Have jQuery process whatever you have in HTML by storing references to values in variables. Details are commented in demo.

```js
/* This is optional, I don't want to write each label manually */
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
  $(this).after(`<label> $${$(this).val()}</label><br>`);
});

/* 
A - Prevent the form from sending data and resetting form
B - Gather all <input type='checkbox'> that are checked into a jQuery Collection
C - Map each checked checkbox value and return value as a real number.
D - Convert that map of numbers into an array and iterate through the array adding each 
    number and return the total sum.
E - Format the value of total as currency and display it in the output tag.
*/

var total;

function totalPrice(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //A
  var checked = $(':checkbox:checked'); //B
  var prices = checked.map(function() { //C
    return Number($(this).val());
  });
  var total = prices.toArray().reduce((subTotal, price) => subTotal + price); //D
  $('.total').text('$' + total.toFixed(2)); //E
};

// When form is submitted call totalPrice()
$('#shop').on('submit', totalPrice);
```

```html
<form id='shop'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='10.59'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='2.00'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='.99'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='65.49'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='81.99'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='6.99'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='5.00'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='199.99'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='20.00'>
  <input type='checkbox' value='47.69'>
  <input type='submit'><br>
  <output class='total'></output>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is in the checkbox value, but the var checked is an array and you are comparing it to a string in the switch-case construct

Comment: Hey Andrea. This is not an answer to the question. Pointing out typos or errors should be done in comments instead. Consider expanding on your answer to provide a solution to the problem instead of just a pointer.